# Clang++16 cant find the sort() function from `std::ranges` on FreeBSD 13.2

Tags: c++, c++20, freebsd, clang++, libc++

I am trying to compile a program that uses `std::ranges::sort()` with clang++16. According to the website https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20, The One Ranges Proposal was implemented in Clangs' libc++ version 13 (partial), 15 (requires `-fexperimental-library` flag), and 16 (without the flag).

I installed clang++16 with `sudo pkg install llvm16`, but when trying to compile the application it errors out with "no matching function for call to 'sort'".

Minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array s {5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3};

    std::ranges::sort(s);
}
```

trying to compile with `clang++16 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -o test` results in this error:

```
test.cpp:9:15: error: no type named 'sort' in namespace 'std::ranges'
        std::ranges::sort(s);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Cannot be reproduced](https://godbolt.org/z/Phqj4fbrM).

Comment: Not familiar with freebsd packaging, but could you check the version of libc++ that is used?

Comment: FreeBSD-13.2 implement the LLVM compiler 14.0.5, and IIRC, the default `libc++` (`/usr/lib/libc++.so`) comes from this version (even if you specify `clang++XX`). Could you try `-fexperimental-library` with your command ?

Comment: @ValeryS. I suspect that probably is the issue. Adding the `-fexperimental-library` doesn't help, it produces the same error.

Comment: Okay, tried replicating it using the FreeBSD 14.0 CURRENT image and using the flag `-fexperimental-library` it successfully compiled the example code. So it was a libc++ version issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `libc++` supplied in the FreeBSD 13.2 image is too old. Using the `-fexperimental-library` flag doesn't help.

I was able to successfully compile the example code with `-fexperimental-library` flag using the FreeBSD 14.0 image.

Comment: Glade you solve your issue, this comply with what I told to you in comment above. Good job.